# Are single mysql statements atomic in MyISAM and InnoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, atomic

For example, I have a row with a column `C1 value = 'clean'`, and two different clients run this query at the **same time**:

```
update T1 set C1 = 'dirty' where Id = 1
```

Without using transactions, is it **guaranteed regardless of engine type** that the value of `mysql_affected_rows()` would be `1` for one client and `0` for the other?

Comment: If you need atomicity, but don't want to use InnoDB tables, [see MySQL lock tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes and No :-)

In both cases, the [access is serialised](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html) (assuming you're using a transactional engine like InnoDB) since they hit the same row, so they won't interfere with each other. In other words, the statements *are* atomic.

However, the affected row count actually depends on your configuration set when you open the connection. The [page for mysql_affected_rows()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) has this to say (my bold):

> For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the number of rows actually **changed**. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is the number of rows **"found"**; that is, matched by the WHERE clause.

And from [the mysql_real_connect page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html):

> CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS: Return the number of **found** (matched) rows, not the number of **changed** rows.

So, in terms of what happens *with* `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` being configured, the affected rows for:

```
UPDATE T1 SET C1 = 'dirty' WHERE id = 1
```

have *nothing* to do with whether the data is *changed,* only what rows *matched.* This would be 1 for both queries.

On the other hand, if `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` was *not* set, the second query would not actually be changing the row (since it's already populated with 'dirty') and would have a row count of zero.

If you wanted the *same* behaviour regardless of that setting (only showing changes), you could use something like:

```
UPDATE T1 SET C1 = 'dirty' WHERE id = 1 AND C1 <> 'dirty'
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that single-statement updates are not atomic for MyIASM ?

Comment: A quick google suggests that MyISAM is mostly atomic as long as you never kill a thread or query.  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=51193

Comment: @sanmai: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html : A locking read, an UPDATE, or a DELETE generally set record locks on every index record that is scanned in the processing of the SQL statement.

Comment: @MyISAM is a crock and should be relegated to where it belongs, alongside all the NoSQL databases :-)

Comment: @sanmai, sorry, misread the query a bit, thinking it was `where c1 = 'clean'`.

Comment: @sanmai In my experience, an update that doesn't change anything in MyISAM gives an affected rows of zero.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is ACID-compliant if you use a transactional storage engine like InnoDB.